# How can I use special character in Document.createElement() - VBA DOM XML

Tags: xml, vba, dom, xmldom

I want to make an XML file using XML DOM in VBA and I can't find a way to set element name using special character. I need it to be named "a:something" but when I add the colon it gives me an error. How should I proceed? Thank you for any help.

Comment: I'm not well-versed in XML so someone enlighten me if I'm wrong but isn't `:` reserved to specify namespace? There's nothing to proceed, change the name. Unless your `a` is actually the namespace then change the namespace declaration?

Comment: Don't tell us something "gives me an error" without telling us what the error is. Error messages are the key to problem solving. They might mean nothing to you, but they mean something to the people who can help you.

Comment: It says that "An empty URI can only be specified
for the default namespace."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you want your element name to be "a:something" presumably means that you want it to have a namespace prefix of "a" and a local name of "something". To create an element in a namespace you need to use the two- or three-argument form of the CreateElement method, specifying the namespace URI and prefix as well as the local name.

For example `doc.CreateElement("a:something", "http://somthing-uri");` where `http://somthing-uri` is the required namespace.